# Left cosets of H in G here

Tags: abstract-algebra

$G=U_4$ and $H=U_2$
so $G=[1,3]$ $H=[1]$
I dont know where to proceed from there, i dont see how adding to the $H$ will give me some form of $G$ if the number of elements are different?
I need to find the left cosets of $H$ in $G$ but not sure how to do that here

Comment: hey! could you be a bit more specific about what you are asking for?

Comment: I need to find the left cosets of H in G but not sure how to do that

Comment: and what is $U_4$?

Comment: oh i forgot to mention H is a subgroup of G, thats all thats given so i assume $U_4=[1,3]$

Comment: so $G=U_4=[1,3]$ but what is $[1,3]$ as a group?

Comment: Im just confused sorry if its obvious im kinda new to abstract algebra

Comment: I understand, it takes a really long time to get used to it. Nothing is obvious in abstract algebra :)

But I have to understand what you mean to be able to help.

So what is $[1,3]$?

Comment: {1,3} is what I mean but couldnt use { } through latex so used [ ] instead. $U_4$ is what i think as the coprime numbers from 1 to 4 ( with relation to 4) which are 1 and 3 and $U_2$ has 1 to 2 so only 1 is coprime (with relation to 2)

Comment: I see. In latex you can include $\{$ writing a backslash in front of it.

Comment: So how would i go about answering this it doesnt really make sense to me of finding cosets of H in G when H and G have different elements

Comment: i am writing an answer right now :)

Comment: Why do you think that $G$ and $H$ have different elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition the set of cosets of $K$ in $L$ is the set
$$
\{lK\mid l\in L\}
$$
where $lK$ means pick an element $l$ from $L$ and multiply through by the different elements of $K$, which is a subgroup of $L$, and ususal notation for this set is $L/K$.

So you have $G=U_4=\mathbb{Z}_4^{\times}$ and $H=U_2=\mathbb{Z}_2^{\times}$. First of all is $H$ a subgroup of $G$? It is of course is since they both are groups under the same operation (modulo $4$ multiplication) and $H\subseteq G$.

We can simply list the cosets due to the fact that the groups have very little element. To form the cosets we need to pick an element from $G$ and multiply through with the different elements from $H$ (luckily you only have one).

$$
G/H=\{1\cdot H, 3\cdot H\}
$$ 
which means that we have two cosets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!